# Print string in always the same position even if prefix-string has dynamic length

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string with dynamic length (S1) that i want to print and i want to add another string after it (S2). S2 should always start at a given length. In my case, after 21 characters. It should not matter how long S1 is.

Given this code:

```
servers = [{"ip": "62.112.10.156", "port": "8150"}, 
           {"ip": "51.15.226.30", "port": "8150"},
           {"ip": "188.165.209.184", "port": "8150"}]

for server in servers:
    ip = server['ip']
    ip = f"IP: {ip}{(' ' * (16 - len(ip)))}"

    port = f"Port: {server['port']}"

    print(f"{ip} {port}")
```

Here is what i get:

```
IP: 62.110.10.136    Port: 8650
IP: 55.15.126.30     Port: 8250
IP: 187.162.209.183  Port: 8030
```

The code does what i need but it's ugly and i'd like to know a more pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use align and width field, see [format-string-syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
for server in servers:
    print ( f"IP: {server['ip']:<16}Port: {server['port']}" )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
servers = [{"ip": "62.112.10.156", "port": "8150"}, 
           {"ip": "51.15.226.30", "port": "8150"},
           {"ip": "188.165.209.184", "port": "8150"}]

for server in servers:
    ip, port = server['ip'], server['port']
    print( f"IP: {ip: <16} Port: {port}")
```

outputs

```
IP: 62.112.10.156    Port: 8150
IP: 51.15.226.30     Port: 8150
IP: 188.165.209.184  Port: 8150
```

Here i did two things, I used the f-string to perform the fixed width formatting and assigned the ip and port values to variables in one line.  I prefer this to accessing the dictionary within the f-string as it makes the f-string easier to read.

Comment: Thanks. The assignment in one line is what i would also use if there would be only two values that i need from the dict but i simplified this example, i actually need more values. But still thanks for it :-)

Comment: @Endogen If you can guarentee that eachdict will have the same keys, in the same order, you could iterate over servers.items() to pull the key-value pairs out and construct the string from that.  You would need to supply a mapping for the field widths but it would be one way to handle multiple attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that what you want to do is to pad the string to 21 characters, and then append the other string. In practice the 'IP: ' takes up 4 chars, so you need to pad 'ip' to 17 chars:

```
servers = [{"ip": "62.112.10.156", "port": "8150"}, 
       {"ip": "51.15.226.30", "port": "8150"},
       {"ip": "188.165.209.184", "port": "8150"}]

for server in servers:
    ip = server['ip']
    ip = f"IP: {ip.ljust(17)}"

    port = f"Port: {server['port']}"

    print(f"{ip} {port}")
```

Comment: This is not what i will end up using but it's actually more clear and easier to understand then format-string-syntax. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for server in servers:
    print('IP:', server['ip'].ljust(16), 'PORT:', server['port'])
```

Result:

```
IP: 62.112.10.156    PORT: 8150
IP: 51.15.226.30     PORT: 8150
IP: 188.165.209.184  PORT: 8150
```